# Pass Jquery + Php search back to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function as follows::

```
 //THIS IS javascript.js
function dosomething(data){
 //splits and do something else
}

$(document).ready(function () {
dosomething();
}
```

Below is a php file from search(database search with jquery and ajax)

```
//THIS IS mysearch.php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $url = $row['url']; 
    $text = $row['text'];
    $argument = $url"."$separator"."$text";
```

);

How do I pass $argument to javascript function? I have tried something like this.

```
echo '<p><a href="javascript:dosomething('.$argument.')">'.$text.'</a></p>';
```

**What would be good way to approach this?**

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried using Javascript/jQuery to load the PHP page? From there you simply output whatever variables you want the JS to have access to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
echo '<p><a href="javascript:dosomething(\''.htmlspecialchars($argument).'\')">'.$text.'</a></p>';
```

// Edit:

If you run into problems with special characters like öäü… you can use json_encode()

Comment: Thanks Oliver, but it didnot work. I should have cleared something: The javascript (.js file) calls this php file(with ajax get). Do you think the javascript function is available to PHP?

Comment: oh you mean the onclick html is inserted with ajax?

Comment: Thanks again, dosomething() function calls a random.php and gets data to run which is fine. I have another php which works with user's search and I want to pass into dosomething(). Its not onclick, its on document.ready(function).

Comment: If you need a more general approach, maybe json or html5 data is for you? http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: I will look on those. Thanks Oliver, I appreciate your time! I just joined so cannot upvote you, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people like using json and ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thanks slattman, I have used jquery json for the search and i passed the results back to HTML with php. I am trying to link those search to pass into javascript. I will look onto json.